# Why isn't there an exclusive hypernym for exponential and logarithmic?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, definition, transcendental-functions

Mathematicians, transcendental is a very broad word.  Why isn't there a narrow word just for exponential and logarithmic?  Transcendental is compared to algebraic, but there is no hyponym of transcendental to denote exclusive set of exponential and logarithmic.

For almost all of software development exponential, logarithmic, and linear time functions are highly relevant, but rarely are other transcendental functions like trigonometric and hyperbolic relevant unless in niche lines of work.  When training junior developers, I always emphasize the importance of exponential and logarithmic, but mathematics has provided no succinct word to denote their importance.

More detail:

As mathematical exponential functions are the inverse of logarithmic functions,  I would expect this special relationship be signified by a specific mathematical word.

Consider other logical supersets.  For example, "transput" is the hypernym of "input" and "output".  "Computerware" is the hypernym of "hardware" and "software".

"Transcendental" is an overshoot for the hypernym of "exponential" and "logarithmic".  Yes, where I typically employ the word is in the context of time complexity, but I anticipate that set/category theory of mathematics has previously prescribed a solution.

Comment: Mathematicians obviously don't need a word for that set of functions, so why do you think they should come up with a name just because it can be used in some other field. If they are the ones with a need shouldn't they solve it?

Comment: I was just waiting for permission.  Thank you.

Comment: And there is also polynomial time. Then there is polylogarithmic time, which has not much to do with what mathematicians call polylogarithms. And of course time complexity like $n \log n$, which comes up a lot but I wouldn't call it either logarithmic or exponential. For time complexity, it seems to me the distinction between algebraic and transcendental is not important, but sublinear, linear, and superlinear is an important distinction.

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing about whether you are talking about the functions that programmers use or the functions that model the time complexity of functions that programmers use. My answer assumed you meant the former, but perhaps not. If the latter, then why not just talk about complexity classes using the standard terminology.

Comment: I don't think that distinction between "programmer functions" and "time complexity functions" is relevant.  See the "More Details" edit.  I couldn't fit my reply in a comment.

Comment: Indeed it is better to clarify the question via an edit than a comment. There are probably better places to ask this question, but wherever you ask it, I recommend to also give a variety of concrete examples showing ways in which you would use such a word in real life. It might result in better answers.

Comment: I'd just say "elementary functions" adding a rider that only the ones that are useful as complexity measures are relevant. See the note I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What is niche about trigonometric and hyperbolic functions? Don't you have students who want to program games or flight simulators or GPS applications or ...?

The functions that I think your students are really interested in are called [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). These functions are the ones that are supported by as library functions in most programming languages and that feature in the most important applications in economics, physics, engineering and ... That's why they are implemented as library functions and that's one of the reasons why they have been given a collective name in pure mathematics.

Note: if you are mainly interested in functions relevant for use as complexity measures, then it doesn't do much harm to talk about the elementary functions as throwing in trigonometric functions and hyperbolic functions doesn't add anything new from the complexity measure point of view: a function with time complexity $|\sin|$ operates in constant time, while a function with time complexity $\sinh$ operates in exponential time.

Comment: I think the question is about time complexity of the implementation, that is, how long the function takes to run, not what value it returns. I could be mistaken.

Comment: @DavidK: I became concerned about that too, hence my subsequent comment on the question. Let's see what the OP comes back with.